# I'm a beginner developer, I'm making meeting management system in ASP.NET so I want to use TimePicker in my peoject

Tags: asp.net

I'm a beginner developer, I'm making meeting management system in ASP.NET  so I want  to use TimePicker and how to transfer `listbox1` items to `listbox2`.

Comment: question should be more specific

Answer (score 2):

logic is like this:

```
 if (list1.SelectedItem != null)  
    {  
    ListItem li = listLeft.SelectedItem;  
    list1.Items.Remove(li);  //if u want remove from list1
    li.Selected = false;  
    list2t.Items.Add(li);  
}
```